# Angular2-Typescript environment causes CPU USAGE 100%

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular

Lately I noticed really slow time to load my angular 2 app after updating a file in my project. the Typescript Compiler detects a file change, and re-compiling my app. The problem is that sometimes it stuck, and it was really annoying.

I checked what's the matter, and I noticed **100% CPU usage** after updating a single file in my app.

[image]

After noticing my OS is 64-bit and google chrome is 32 bit, I have installed **64-bit version of Google Chrome**, but node.js takes more than half of the CPU within one file update!

[image]

My Angular 2 is pretty big (about 20 components).

My assumption is that the compiler is loading hundreds of typescript files at once as I see in the console (this is small part of it, which suppose all of you have).

and Google Chrome loads **840 requests** on browser reload!

Anyone has any ideas he can share to maximize the environment performance with lower CPU usage?

My computer specs are pretty fine: i5 processor with 8GB ram

Comment: typescript re-compile every files that linked. and your i5 cpu should have 4 cpu, total 400%, you still have 300% CPU free, imo. 840 requests too much though. you need to concat some files during build process.

Comment: @YOU I believe Task manager shows overall CPU utilization, so 100% is maximum regardless of number of cores. 

I have the same problem even on Angular tutorial app with as few as 5 small components.